# How can I return more than 10 buckets from an aggs, multi-terrms query using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using Elasticsearch 8.4.1 and I'm trying to return more than 10 buckets from this working query:

```
GET vaersdata_2/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "age_died after_shot": {
        "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [{ 
          "field": "AGE_YRS"
        }, {
          "field": "DIED"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I added size into the mix, but after numerous failed attempts, it throws an error.  This query didn't show errors in the console until I ran it:

```
GET vaersdata_2/_search
{
  "aggs": {
      "size": 0,
    "age_died after_shot": {
        "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [{ 
          "field": "AGE_YRS",
          "size" : 100
        }, {
          "field": "DIED"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then I get this error:

> "type": "parsing_exception",
> "reason": "Aggregation definition for [size starts with a [VALUE_NUMBER], expected a [START_OBJECT].",
> "line": 3,
> "col": 15   },   "status": 400

I've seen size used as a solution for this using nested term queries, but how do I do this for an aggs, multi-terrms query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

Quite close, but the `size` arguments is not place in the right spot.

## Solution

```json
GET vaersdata_2/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "age_died after_shot": {
        "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [{ 
          "field": "AGE_YRS"
        }, {
          "field": "DIED"
        }],
        "size" : 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following query has been tested with kibana 8.4.1

```json
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "multi_bucket": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "size": 12,
        "terms": [{
          "field": "customer_first_name.keyword" 
        }, {
          "field": "customer_last_name.keyword"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still seeing a 400 bad request error with this.  I think I had tried this before in my many attempts.  It may be you can't use size with this and need some other property?

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: 8.4.1. I downloaded the latest last week.

Comment: And the 2nd query does not work either ?

Comment: Wait I just noticed the 2nd `size: 0` parameters and edited my answer

Comment: Yep that did it! Interesting.